# Xcode Picker View is jumping to another value instead of the selected one

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview, pickerview

I'm using Xcode Version 13.1

I use UIPickerView, but when I choose value its jump to another one, I have 10 items `[item 0 ... item 9]`
when I choose **item 1** the value jumps to 6, how can I solve it?

[Here I'm choosing "Item 1" but Xcode choose and print 6 instead of 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CGfH.png)

[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUJes.gif)

my code:

```
import UIKit

class LengthViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

let pickerData = ["Item 0","Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8","Item 9"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
 }
}

extension LengthViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate{
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        print(row)
        return pickerData[row]
    }

}
extension LengthViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource{
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you record a GIF of what is exactly happening?

Comment: yes, here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUJes.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're printing at a bad moment. You printing in `pickerView(_:titleForRow:forComponent)`. This is like looking to see how the sausage is made. You are assuming that just because you *choose* a certain row, that is also the row that the picker view wants the *title* for. But there is actually no connection between those two things. The row that needs its title is not the row you chose.

Instead, implement `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` and put your `print` call there. You will see that when you choose a row, that is indeed the row that the picker view thinks you chose.

Comment: Thank you! you helped me a lot!!